# Where to start with Lie Algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Should I start with An Introduction to Lie Algebras by K Erdmann and M Wildon or jump straight to Brian Hall's Book on Lie Groups, Lie Algebras? Both are stated to be elementary but I'm not sure where to start?

Is it smarter to start with Erdmann and Wildon's book on lie algebras then move on to Hall's Book? I know Linear Algebra, Abstract Algebra, some basic Point Set Topology, a bit of Real Analysis.

Comment: Without knowing anything about these books, I feel like it's going to be impossible to tell you what you should do without knowing you. I also feel like questions about what an individual should do are in general off topic, unless they are more generic so that others can also use them. If you wanted to compare these books as references or as study materials, that might be more on topic.

Comment: I would start with Brian Hall at least until chapter 7, then you can go to Erdmann, then to Humphrey then whatever...

Answer (score 1):

Since Erdmann and Wildon's book is title "Lie Algebras", I am not sure exactly what you mean by "light on lie algebras". It is an excellent book.

Comment: I guess I said "light" because compared to Hall's book its a bit lighter on certain materials that's covered.